# Merge 2 dataframe depending on column values

Tags: python, regex, pandas, split

Hello I have a dataframe such as :

**Df1**

```
Groups   Names                          COLs  COLe
G1     ABC_DEF.1:2-300():Canis_lupus    2     300
G1     SEQUENCE1                        NA    NA
G1     SEQUENCE2                        NA    NA
G1     SEQUENCE3                        NA    NA
G1     ABC_DEF.1:400-600():Canis_lupus  400   600
G1     IJK_LMN.1:20-200():Bos_taurus    20    200
G2     OP_D:500-1000():Felis_catus      500   1000
G2     Sequence3                        NA    NA
```

and another df  such as :

**df2**

```
COL1       COL2       COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6 Species
ABC_DEF.1  SEQUENCE1  20   80   A    1    Canis_lupus
ABC_DEF.1  SEQUENCE2  500  548  C    3    Canis_lupus
QKC_DEF.2  SEQUENCE2  500  548  Z    O    Canis_lupus
ABC_DEF.1  SEQUENCE4  520  800  T    9    Canis_lupus
IJK_LMN.1  SEQUENCE1  10   18   D    4    Bos_taurus
AQK_LM9.1  SEQUENCE1  10   18   P    5    Bos_taurus
IJK_LMN.1  SEQUENCE1  30   50   U    0    Bos_taurus
IJK_LMN.1  SEQUENCE3  30   176  E    5    Bos_taurus
OP_D       SEQUENCE3  600  700  F    6    Felis_catus
OP_D       SEQUENCE1  539  878  G    7    Felis_catus
OP_S       SEQUENCE4  20   78   H    8    Felis_catus
```

and the idea is to create a new df that will be a merged between all the dataframe

here is the expected result

```
Groups Names                            COL2        COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6
G1     ABC_DEF.1:2-300():Canis_lupus   SEQUENCE1   20   80   A    1
G1     ABC_DEF.1:400-600():Canis_lupus SEQUENCE2   500  548  B    2
G1     IJK_LMN.1:20-200():Bos_taurus   SEQUENCE1   30   50   U    0
G1     IJK_LMN.1:20-200():Bos_taurus   SEQUENCE3   30   176  E    5
G2     OP_D:500-1000():Felis_catus     SEQUENCE3   600  700  F    6
```

the idea is to parse each `Groups` in `Df1`
Let's take the `G1` as en exemple:

`ABC_DEF.1:2-300():Canis_lupus` is in the `df2`,

then I look into that `df` if I have `COL2` that corresponds to element present in `Names` :

I have `SEQUENCE1` and `SEQUENCE2` that are in the same groups :

then if `COL3` and `COL4` are between the `COLs` - `Cole` (here `2-300`),

so `SEQUENCE1` is `20-80` then I add the row into the new df :

```
Groups Names                            COL2        COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6
G1     ABC_DEF.1:2-300():Canis_lupus   SEQUENCE1   20   80   A    1
```

`SEQUENCE2` is `500-548` so it is above `2-300`

then I get interested in the second names in `G1` : `ABC_DEF.1:400-600():Canis_lupus`

again there are `SEQUENCE1` and `SEQUENCE2` but here only `SEQUENCE2` is in the range `400-600` so I add only this one

```
Groups Names                            COL2        COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6
G1     ABC_DEF.1:2-300():Canis_lupus   SEQUENCE1   20   80   A    1
G1     ABC_DEF.1:400-600():Canis_lupus SEQUENCE2   500  548  B    2
```

now `IJK_LMN.1:20-200():Bos_taurus`, I got to the `df2`

`SEQUENCE1` corresponds and is in the range `20-200`

```
Groups Names                            COL2        COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6
G1     ABC_DEF.1:2-300():Canis_lupus   SEQUENCE1   20   80   A    1
G1     ABC_DEF.1:400-600():Canis_lupus SEQUENCE2   500  548  B    2
G1     IJK_LMN.1:20-200():Bos_taurus   SEQUENCE1   30   50   U    0
```

etc

Does someone have an idea with pandas and python ?

I guess we should use merge and split the Names in order to get each part :

ex:

```
ABC_DEF.1:2-300():Canis_lupus
```

will have to be splited into :

1. ABC_DEF.1 (everything before the first `:`)
2. Canis_lupus (part after the last `:`)

Comment: if you tried using `pandas.merge`? you can specify multiple columns from each dataframe as the keys

Comment: Hello @PaulH, yes I know how tu use pd.merge but  I do not really know how to deal with this question of range

Comment: sounds like your best bet is to go a more general merge on a few of the columns and filter that result for your more value range-dependent criteria. it'd be nice to have what you've already tried as a launching off point

Answer (score 0):

First, you should consider take the following steps:

1 - Remove rows containing only SEQUENCE1, SEQUENCE2, etc etc from the `df1`. From what I understand, they do not serve because there is no range and specific name.
2- Remove everything after the first ':' from the column`Names`

Then, you can do the following:

3 - Merge both dataframes using the pandas.merge:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df1,df2, how = 'inner', left_on = 'Name', right_on = 'COL1')
```

4 - Filter out your resulting dataframe based on the condition you stated about `COL3` and `COL4` between `COLs` and `COLe`.

When you do the inner join like that, you will get duplicate results because of the COL1 having more than one value for COL2 (the sequences). So you can easily filter out the correct results by the condition you want.

You can check more on SQL comparison with pandas here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html

Please, let me know if my answer is of any help.

Comment: Okay I succeed to reach the 3th part ! now I need to find a way to remove the COL3 COL4 that are note in the range of Cols and Cole for each line, do you have an idea ?

Comment: Good! Try this:

`df_final = df_merged[(df_merged['COL3'] >= df_merged['COLs']) & (df_merged['COL4'] <= df_merged['COLe'])]`   .
That way, you will only keep the values that are between the values of COLs and COLe
Then you can drop the unwanted columns with df.drop() method. If this answer is enough for you, please mark it as the accepted answer. =)